# Passport serializeUser() is not called with this authenticate() callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

Using passport.js, I write the route this way so I have access to the MongoDb document `userDoc`. But, when doing it this way...  `passport.serializeUser()` will never be called and the `req` object will be missing `user`.

```
auth.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, userDoc, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      // I don't think !userDoc will ever happen because of mongo upsert
      if (!userDoc) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
      res.cookie('facebookPicUrl', userDoc.value.facebook.picture, {maxAge : 9999999,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
        signed: false
      });

      res.redirect('http://localhost:9000/users')
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

But if I write it this way, the `req.user` is there as it should be:

```
auth.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
  .get(passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
       function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('http://localhost:9000/users')
    });
```

How can I make this to where `passport.serializeUser` is called and `user` exists on `req` and I also have access to the mongoDb object?

Comment: I'm not sure if they have updated the docs but this is what is stated at the end of the custom callback section: "The callback can use the arguments supplied to handle the authentication result as desired. Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and send a response."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since you are using the custom authentication callback you are responsible for establishing the session.

> Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's
>   responsibility to establish a session (by calling `req.login()`) and
>   send a response.

`req.login()` assigns the `user` object to the request object `req` as `req.user` once the login operation completes.

You can see for example that in the documentation `req.login()` is explicitly called in the custom callback:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Wow! As far as I understand this was not documented right on the Passport.js website. They say that passport.authenticate() calls req.login() but I was not aware that it had to be called manually if providing a custom callback. The docs are so vague!

Comment: I agree, this is not documented on the site at all @OzzyTheGiant

Comment: You saved my day. Spent a lot of time trying figuring out and adding logIn solved the problem with authentication